# Center Responsive CSS circle with centered text inside of a parent DIV

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I have recently started working on `CSS` for a four button web layout, that I intend to plug into a `Wordpress theme`.

I am focused right now on two things - 4 buttons that are equal-radius circles, and a fully responsive layout.

I found a fantastic method for creating responsive circles with centered text at: [this website](http://littledice.me/2014/04/16/responsive-circles-with-css/)

The only issue here is getting them to center vertically inside of a `parent DIV`.  Absolute positioning does not work, and I don't think it can, because the button height is unknown.

I'm currently playing around with CSS transform, and it's the closest I've gotten so far.  I have applied the vertical center class called centerme to various divs, as seen here.

CSS:

```
.circle {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      background-color:purple;
}
.circle-border {
      border: 1px solid black;
}
.circle:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      padding-top: 100%;
}
.circle-inner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
}
.nav-text {
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 1em;
      line-height: 1em;
      font-size: 1em;
}
.centerme{
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(50%);
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="button4" class="buttoncontainer centerme"><!-- start button4 -->
        <div class="circle circle-border"><!-- start circle construction-->
            <div class="circle-inner">
                <div class="nav-text">
                    <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end circle construction-->
    </div> <!-- end button4 -->
```

Sorry if this issue has already been posted.  Thanks in advance

**[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sshrugg/u3F99/4/)** contains the entire layout

Comment: Could you please explain where should the `circle` buttons be centered

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 ways to make something vertical:

**1.vertiacl-align:middle** (which applies to inline elements)

**2.position:absolute; top:0 ;bottom:0 ;margin:auto;**

but none of them can be apply to a float div.

I suggest you change your html code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove float: reft style from ".buttoncontainer", Like this:

```
.buttoncontainer {
    display: block;
    /* float: left; */
    margin-left: 4%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
}
```

This will arrange the buttons vertivcally.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .centerme class from buttoncontainer div.
Remove the  and add a container div with a clearfix class. You need to mention the css for clearfix as follows:

```
 .clearfix:after
{ 
 content: ".";  
 display: block; 
 height: 0; 
 clear: both; 
 visibility: hidden; 
}
```

remove the li for each  tag.

For #navbar add display:table and for the new clearfix div add display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle.

Your new structure would be as follows:

```
<div id="navbar" style="display:table">  <!-- start navbar -->
<div class="clearfix" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle">
<div id="button1" class="buttoncontainer"><!-- start button1 -->
        <div class="circle circle-border"><!-- start circle construction-->
            <div class="circle-inner">
                <div class="nav-text">
                    <a href="#">ONE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end circle construction-->

    </div>
....
</div>
</div>
```